# Azure Autopilot: Serial Numbers for Custom Built PCs

Tags: azure, deployment, mdm, intune

I've been using autopilot with some of our Dell workstations and I've used the Powershell scripts online to generate the CSV files for importing our current devices. But when expanding to the rest of our workstations, I realized that the following doesn't work for our Custom workstations.

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Our custom built machines don't have Serial Numbers in the BIOS. I've been debating just making something up, but I was wondering if anyone else had a better solution to the problem?

Ideally, something that could replace that line in the script would be preferred as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turns out that there was no need to change anything in the first place.

The default entry from

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Will show the serial number as "System Serial Number" which is a perfectly acceptable result for Autopilot. You just use that as the Serial Number for the machine when you import your CSV to Autopilot and it will work just fine.